# Obtain all trees after deleting one or more leaves of a given (non-binary) tree

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, tree

Given a tree (non-binary), what would be the optimal way to obtain **all** the trees that emerge after deleting **one** or **more** **leaf** nodes from the original tree?

I am looking for a simple Pythonic implementation (without using any graph libraries) of the algorithm, or pseudo code.

As an example:

For a tree:

```
     A 
   / | \
  B  C  D
 / \     \
E   F     G
```

I want to get the following trees as output:

```
     A 
   / | \
  B  C  D


     A 
   /   \
  B     D


     A 
   /   \
  B     D
 / \     \
E   F     G


     A 
   / | \
  B  C  D
 /       \
E         G


     A 
   / | \
  B  C  D
   \     \
    F     G
```

.... and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to identify all the leaves of the input tree, count them, and then increment a "mask" number whose binary bits indicate whether the corresponding leaf should be included or excluded. Finally create a function that copies a given tree, taking into account such a mask number.

First, I'll assume a versatile Node constructor, which accepts the value for the node, but then also any number of arguments that will become the child nodes of this node:

```
class Node:
    # This constructor accepts any number of children as arguments
    def __init__(self, value, *children):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children  # This is a list (that could be empty)
```

Then define these utility functions (which could also be methods of the `Node` class):

```
def get_leaves(node):  # Depth first traversal yielding all leaves
    if node.children:
        for child in node.children:
            yield from get_leaves(child)
    else:
        yield node

def print_tree(root, tab=""):  # Very simple print implementation
    print(tab + str(root.value))
    for child in root.children:
        print_tree(child, tab + "  ")
```

Now to the actual logic:

```
def copy_tree(root, mask):
    def recur(node):
        nonlocal mask
        if not node.children:
            # Extract the next bit from the mask and let it determine whether
            # to create the leaf copy or not: 
            keep = mask & 1
            mask >>= 1
            if not keep:
                return
        # Get the children through recursion and kick out None returns
        return Node(node.value, *filter(None, map(recur, node.children)))
    
    return recur(root)

def get_trimmed_trees(root):
    leaf_count = sum(1 for _ in get_leaves(root))
    # Iterate all possible mask numbers (except the one that keeps all leaves)
    return [copy_tree(root, mask) for mask in range(2 ** leaf_count - 1)]
```

And finally a demo that creates the tree you provided as example, and runs the algorithm:

```
root = Node("A",
    Node("B", Node("E"), Node("F")),
    Node("C"),
    Node("D", Node("G"))
)

print_tree(root)
for trimmed_root in get_trimmed_trees(root):
    print("===")
    print_tree(trimmed_root)
```